# Why do all of my R installs fail?

Tags: r, installation

Every package I try to install is met with the following error:

```
 * installing *source* package ‘dichromat’ ...
** package ‘dichromat’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package ‘dichromat’
    finding HTML links ... done
    colorschemes                            html
    dalton                                  html
Error: invalid regular expression '^[[:blank:]]*
'
* removing ‘/newhome/vdp5/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/dichromat’
ERROR: dependency ‘dichromat’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/newhome/vdp5/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/scales’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpVXl3tg/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("scales") :
  installation of package ‘dichromat’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("scales") :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have no idea why this installation keeps failing and have been unable to make any progress in potentially hacking together a solution.

My session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Exactly which packages did you try to install? Which parts of the error message are exactly the same? What OS and R version are you using (share your `sessionInfo()`)?

Comment: @MrFlick Installing the 'scales' package, but the failure takes place with the dichromat package. I've updated with session info. Thanks for the help!